# C# raise event in Child Form Called From Parent Form

Tags: c#, events, parent-child

I have a tool strip menu in my parent form and I'm loading my child forms into a panel as user controls. I need to fire an event in my child form when the user clicks on the menu strip in my parent form.

Here is the event in the parent control:

```
//Character Name
private void randomNameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_SQL_Settings.TabControl == "Character Builder")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must be in the Character Builder Screen
                       To Generate A Random Character Name, Please Try Again.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

//Character
private void randToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_SQL_Settings.TabControl == "Character Builder")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must be in the Character Builder Screen
                           To Generate A Random Character, Please Try Again.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is where I Build my child form in the Parent form:

```
case "Character Builder":
    {
        Character_Builder CC = new Character_Builder();

        panCC.Controls.Clear();
        CC.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panCC.Controls.Add(CC);

        CC.Main_Menu += Main_Menu;
        break;
    }
```

And here is the functions I want to fire off when the user clicks on the parent form menu strip items

```
private void Generate_Raondom_Character()
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private void Generate_Random_Character_Name()
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

I have added these two events in my child form but I think they need to be in my parent form.

Events:

```
public event EventHandler Random_Character;
        public event EventHandler Random_Name;
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work? Sample would be great. I know how to do it in Vb just not c#.

Comment: its friging *Form* not _Forum_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one solution. This is not what I wanted to do but it seems to work. I am looping through the controls in my child forum until I find the control I want and editing the controls text. I wanted to use events but I guess this works too. If anyone has better ways to do this please share:

```
if (_SQL_Settings.TabControl == "Character Builder")
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = _SQL.Random_Character_Name();

                foreach (Control Parentctrl in panCC.Controls)
                {
                    if (Parentctrl.Name == "Character_Builder")
                    {
                        foreach (Control Childctrl in Parentctrl.Controls)
                        {
                            if (Childctrl.Name == "cbFirstName")
                            {
                                Childctrl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["First_Name"].ToString();
                            }

                            if (Childctrl.Name == "cbLastName")
                            {
                                Childctrl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
                            }

                            if (Childctrl.Name == "cbCharacterTitle")
                            {
                                Childctrl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Character_Title"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```